# How to access HTML element without ID?

Tags: javascript, dom, xhtml

For instance in the snippet below - how do I access the h1 element knowing the ID of parent element (header-inner div)?

```
<div id='header-inner'> 
   <div class='titlewrapper'> 
      <h1 class='title'> 
      Some text I want to change
      </h1> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you merely looking for a H1 descendant of a given DIV? Or do you want to identify it by class name? Or are you specifically interested in finding an H1 element with class "title" that is a child of a DIV with a class of "titlewrapper" which in turn is a child of the DIV with id "header-inner"?

Comment: I just wanna be able to get h1 within a div with given id (in my case header-inner)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
function findFirstDescendant(parent, tagname)
{
   parent = document.getElementById(parent);
   var descendants = parent.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
   if ( descendants.length )
      return descendants[0];
   return null;
}

var header = findFirstDescendant("header-inner", "h1");
```

Finds the element with the given ID, queries for descendants with a given tag name, returns the first one. You could also loop on `descendants` to filter by other criteria; if you start heading in that direction, i recommend you check out a pre-built library such as jQuery (will save you a good deal of time writing this stuff, it gets somewhat tricky).

Comment: Cheers bud - the script looks great, I'll give it a try and mark as answer

Comment: This is a terribly delayed question, but how would I determine whether I want the first, second, third, or more descendant?

Comment: Gonna depend entirely on your needs, @brandon - maybe you want to highlight a specific paragraph, maybe you're looking for a child with a particular bit of content.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm looking for a child with a particular bit of content

Answer (score 9):

If you were to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as mentioned by some posters, you can get access to the element very easily like so (though technically this would return a collection of matching elements if there were more than one H1 descendant):

```
var element = $('#header-inner h1');
```

Using a library like JQuery makes things like this trivial compared to the normal ways as mentioned in other posts.  Then once you have a reference to it in a jQuery object, you have even more functions available to easily manipulate its content and appearance.

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that there is only one H1 element in your div:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('header-inner');
var element = parent.GetElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
```

Going through descendants,as Shog9 showed, is a good way too.

Comment: Case matters: `getElementsByTagName` (lower case "g"s)

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few years since this question was asked and answered. In modern DOM, you could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
document.querySelector('#header-inner h1').textContent = 'Different text';
```

```html
<div id='header-inner'> 
   <div class='titlewrapper'> 
      <h1 class='title'> 
      Some text I want to change
      </h1> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing it with your current markup is:

`document.getElementById('header-inner').getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'new text';`

This assumes your H1 tag is always the first one within the `'header-inner'` element.

Comment: And this ought to be: document.getElementById('header-inner').getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].forstChild.nodeValue = 'new text';

Answer (score 1):

To get the children nodes, use `obj.childNodes`, that returns a collection object.

To get the first child, use `list[0]`, that returns a node.

So the complete code should be:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('header-inner');
var divTitleWrapper = div.childNodes[0];
var h1 = divTitleWrapper.childNodes[0];
```

If you want to iterate over all the children, comparing if they are of class “title”, you can iterate using a for loop and the `className` attribute.

The code should be:

```js
var h1 = null;
var nodeList = divTitleWrapper.childNodes;
for (i =0;i < nodeList.length;i++){
    var node = nodeList[i];
    if(node.className == 'title' && node.tagName == 'H1'){
        h1 = node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I get the H1 elements value in a div where the H1 element which has CSS class="myheader":

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("mydiv")
                    .getElementsByTagName("H1");

for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
{
    if(nodes.item(i).getAttribute("class") == "myheader")
        alert(nodes.item(i).innerHTML);
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <h1 class="myheader">Hello</h1>
</div>
```

I would also recommend to use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) if you need a heavy parsing for your DOM.