# get ul in javascript and append li

Tags: javascript, html-lists

What I'm trying to do is creating a `<li>` which should be added to the existing `<ul>`
I want to append the textnode to the  without giving it an ID. 
I try to do it with pure JavaScript, without jQuery.

What I got so far (and it does not work ):

```
function addElement () {
    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Teststring in <li>");
    newLi.appendChild(text);
    var ulnew = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')
    ulnew.appendChild(newLi)    
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="addElement()">
    <ul></ul>
</body>
```

Anyone who can help out?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access HTML element without ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236624/how-to-access-html-element-without-id)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a node list.  You need to get a specific tag from that:

```
ulnew[0].appendChild(newLi);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eKeFN/