# FIll in textbox in webbrowser has no id

Tags: vb6

here is the website `http://www.checker.freeproxy.ru/checker/`
am trying to fill in the textbox using webbrowser how ever the textbox in webbrowser does not have any id at all here is the html source to the textbox.

```
<p class="lead">paste proxies you'd like to check below (100 max per time)</p>

    <form method="post" action="/checker/" id="checker-form">
        <fieldset>
            <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <p id="checker-form-toolbar">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-checking-text="Checking proxies...">Check proxies</button>
        </p>
```

i even tried

```
wb.Document.getElementById("textarea").focus
wb.Document.getElementById("textarea").innerText = Text4.Text
```

it dont work

Comment: Look at things like `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: HI Slaks , first of all i want to thank you for taking the time to reply sir , may i ask if u can maybe show me how this part is done as i am asking for little guidence from the professionals cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access HTML element without ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236624/how-to-access-html-element-without-id)

Comment: its not the same programming language