# Comparing two numbers of a webpage using js console

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare two numbers on a webpage by using their Class names.

I have seen some answers using GetelementbyID("") but my webpage doesn't have any Id and it just have class.
Can anyone help?

```
<span class="sc-hSdWYo ktoHrC">0.0023</span>'Number1
and
<span class="sv-hdESYo ioIng">0.0023</span>'Number2
```

I want this code to alert whenever Num1 become Bigger than number 2.

Comment: Try to use `getElementsByClassName('sc-hSdWYo')[0]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access HTML element without ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236624/how-to-access-html-element-without-id)

Comment: thanks for your reply. when I use your code the alert is :object HTMLSpanElement. here is my code: ```var x=document.getElementsByClassName('sc-hSdWYo ktoHrC')[0]; alert(x)```

Comment: try to use `getElementsByClassName('sc-hSdWYo')[0].innerHTML` to get the text of span tag

Comment: Thanks you all, Specially @arisalsaila. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [`document.getElementsByClass`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) name method

```
num1 = document.getElementsByClassName('sc-hSdWYo ktoHrC')[0].innerHTML;
num2 = document.getElementsByClassName('sv-hdESYo ioIng')[0].innerHTML;

if( num1 > num2 ) {
//alert code goes here
}
```