# How to get the option value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code:

```
<SELECT onChange="chData(this,this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">MIPS
<OPTION VALUE="_XXCEC-LRSYSCPU">% CEC
<OPTION VALUE="_nIFL-LRSYSCPU">nIFL
</SELECT>
```

and I need to take with javascript all the value (not the text) of the option value that I have in the HTML PAGE.
The problem is that In know that the value contains the word "-LRSYSCPU", but I don't know the previous part (Example _MIPS).
the second problem is that I don't have the ID in the select so how can I take the option value? 
I have seen that people use this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("elementId");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

but I don't have the id so i dont know how to proceed..

I need to create an array with this three values : _MIPS-LRSYSCPU,  _XXCEC-LRSYSCPU and _nIFL-LRSYSCPU.
Thanks

Comment: Then put an id on it so you can select it? `<SELECT id="YOUR_ID_HERE" onChange="chData(this,this.value)">`. Or select by tag name 'select'. Look into `querySelectorAll()` if you can use it. It's like getElementByX, all in one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access HTML element without ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236624/how-to-access-html-element-without-id)

Comment: well you are passing in `this`.... Are you not referencing the element with that argument? Can you not add a class or data attribute to the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab all the option values in the page that include the substring "LRSYSCPU" you can use this code:

```js
// Grab all the options in the page
const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');

// `filter` out the options that have the "LRSYSCPU" substring
// in their values
const filtered = [...options].filter(({ value }) => value.includes('-LRSYSCPU'));

// Iterate over those filtered options with `map` and return only
// the values
const values = filtered.map(({ value }) => value);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<select>
<option value="temp">temp</option>
<option value="_MIPS-LRSYSCPU">MIPS</option>
<option value="_XXCEC-LRSYSCPU">% CEC</option>
<option value="temp2">temp2</option>
<option value="_nIFL-LRSYSCPU">nIFL</option>
</select>
```

**Documentation**

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It works!!!! Thank youu soo much for the fast answer!! I cannot add the ID so in this way it works perfectly! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only single select on the whole page then you can use -

> let selectTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

then it will return you array of HTMLCollection [select]. Now you can get your select using selectTags[0], which is an object of type **HTMLCollection**. This object contains **childNodes**. Iterating over child nodes will give you all options and there values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to find all options that end with `-LRSYSCPU`. You can then loop over them and test whether they're selected.

```
let options = document.querySelector("option[value$=-LRSYSCPU]");
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
        value = options[i].value;
        text = options[i].text;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you use jQuery, it has a selector extension `:selected`, so you can do this without a loop:

```
var option = $("option[value$=-LRSYSCPU]:selected");
var value = option.val();
var text = option.text();
```